# How to get rid of "git(main)" in terminal for mac

Tags: git, macos, terminal

A few years ago, I added some theme to my terminal a few years back. I've not been bothered ever since to remove the "git(main)" that displays throughout my terminal until now. Does anyone know how to remove it ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: are you using zsh or bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prompt customization is most likely from oh-my-zsh. [Instructions for removing oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-oh-my-zsh). If you want to keep oh-my-zsh, and remove only the git portion of the prompt, you will need to open `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme` and remove `$(git_prompt_info)` from the file.